# Need to get the Cursor inserted data With in MySQL cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am writing a MySQL stored procedure with cursor to process the data row by row. And I am fetching the data in a cursor and processing it by inserting into the same table where I am fetching it. Since I am using the cursor I could get the inserted record inside the cursor. I need to get that record inserted by cursor to process repeatedly. However, I am unable to get the newly inserted data using any method in the same cursor. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you committed the insertion prior to querying the data:

cur.connection.commit()

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the reply. Here nothing to do with commit. I am fetching data through cursor, Its automatically getting committed. However, It has to close the cursor and has to re-fetch the data again. Please give your valuable suggestion on this.